# How do I display content from a HTTPresponse object in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a MEAN stack application in which I am accessing the node backend as an API. I am able to set the response message and am also able to see it in the response object in my browser. How will I be able to access this message and display it in my HTML?

Screenshot of Network tab in browser showing the response object:

[[image: Screenshot of Network tab in browser showing the response object]]

Comment: callback of the ajax caller will have data as a param and param.message will give you access to the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very broad question.  Really, what you've said is - "I've got the server-side, how do I do the client-side."
Anyway, you can use Angular.  With Angular, you can do this:

```
$http.get('/items').then(function(response) {
    $scope.data = response.data;
});
```

That gets the data to Angular(mind you, this is simplified), which can then show it in the html through templates like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data">{{ item.name }}</div>
```

In your example, you're actually showing a null result.  I would actually be managing the messaging for this in the Angular template something like this:

```
<div ng-if="!data">No items</div>
```

Actually, you're showing a result that appears to be an unsuccessful user lookup.  For that, you'd be creating a script like this(again, this is simplified):

```
$http.get('/users/' + id).then(function(response) {
    $scope.user = response.data.user;
});
```

and a template like this:

```
<div ng-if="user">
    <h1>{{ user.name }}</h1>
    <h3>Favorite Books<h3>
    <div ng-repeat="book in user.books">{{ book }}</div>
</div>
<div ng-if="!user">Couldn't find user</div>
```

Hope this helps.